# Values get appended to each array/list in a dictionary except just specific one

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a loop like this:

```py
for item in items:
    print(item) # string
    buy_price = # long, but works
    sell_price = # also long but works

    self.market[item]["latestBuyPrices"].append(buy_price)
    self.market[item]["latestSellPrices"].append(sell_price)
```

Each element in `self.market` is like this:

```py
'ITEM_ID': {'id': 'ITEM_ID',  # the key name and this value are the same
            'name': 'Item Name',  # the item name in a nice readable format
            'latestBuyPrices': [],
            'latestSellPrices': []}
```

So, accessing one item's data should be as easy as `self.market[ITEM_ID]`
However, on the last two lines in the above loop, for some reason the price gets added to the list of prices of EVERY item instead of only the item the loop is currently on. Meaning that if there are 8 items each of those arrays will have 8 values instead of just one

I have checked buy_price, self_price and self.market already and it is structured correctly

What could be causing this?

It might be worth saying that the for loop is inside an async function

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: Alright, I'll make one

Comment: But somehow, when you create `self.market`, you are re-using the same list.

Comment: I have a list of all the item IDS (its called items) and a start function where self.market is created and I loop through items, creating a new key:value pair where key is the item ID, and value is that template, then I modify the "id" and "name" keys, I don't quite get what you mean by I'm re-using the same list?

Comment: Show us how you create the dictionary. We can't help if you show us only the piece of code where you think the problem is, while excluding other important parts of it

Comment: @DarioVuksan don't tell us *in english*. **Show us the code that does this**. I mean that the most likely explanation is that each item `dict` has *the same list object*, that would explain "for some reason the price gets added to the list of prices of EVERY item instead of only the item the loop is currently on". In any case, you have to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is the minimum working reproducible example https://hastebin.com/otisupozuq.rb (The start() just loads the items into `market`, the loop is where the problem happens)

Comment: Do not post links to code, post code as formatted text in the question itself. In any case, it's exactly as I suspected, you are *re-using* the same lists, `template.copy()` is a shallow copy. The problem is what you are doing in `start`

Comment: Then, how can I fix it? If I use just template instead of template.copy(), then each market's element is a reference to the template and the next two lines automatically change it for every market element